# Display a Portrait mode app in Landscape mode on a tv connected via HDMI

Tags: ios, external-display

I have an animation used for eye tests that has horizontal stripes that move up and down.  The app orientation is strictly Portrait mode.  The patient rotates the iPhone to landscape mode and watches the stripes move left and right.  If the iPhone is plugged into a tv with an HDMI cable the image is strictly portrait mode and the stripes move vertically regardless of the physical orientation of the iPhone.  Selecting Landscape mode in XCode target does not work.  Is there a way to make the image on the tv screen display in landscape mode without rewriting the app?

Comment: Why not make the app strictly landscape and have the lines move horizontally?

Comment: Also, if you're targeting tv users a different approach might be a tvOS app. In most cases you don't need design your iOS app specifically for connecting to a tv via HDMI, as it is a rare use case.

Comment: Thanks, modifying it to be pure landscape mode is probably the only real option.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ I'm so sorry that was an answer to another question! I copied and pasted the wrong thing.